# LibApp.so missing in .APK with firebase-unity.sdk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, gradle

I am using Unity 5.5 and the firebase-unity-sdk and building for android with Gradle.

However, the firebase LibApp.so file is missing in the .apk file that is built.

How do I troubleshoot this issue?